# Size of an array in memory in php

Tags: php, memory

I am trying to figure out the size of a variable in php.

The reason i need to do this is because if it is over 1mb i need to use a different form of caching rather than memcache as memcache has a limit of 1mb.

I am using the below:

```
 $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
 $this->results= $dataReader->readAll();
 $this->end_memory = memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

The results are coming back as 50mb which is very inaccurate. I have looked at str length also but the data is an array. Can someone let me know the most accurate way of detecting the size of a variable in php.

Comment: Languages that allow you to do this are the exception, and PHP is not one of them. You 'll have to attack the problem differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [MultipartCache](https://github.com/olekukonko/MultipartCache) it's a simple class that extends memcache to help you split the arrays or string automatically

**Simple Test**

```
$cache = new Mcache\Main();
$cache->addserver("127.0.0.1");  // Local memecache server

$cache->set($key, file_get_contents("large_image.jpg"));

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $cache->get($key); // large image for cache
```

If you are just interested in the size of of your data then

```
$data = serialize($this->results);
echo strlen($data) . " bytes";
```

Comment: this is what i am using- there is no point in using memcache though i guess for encoding decoding if the contents are less than 1mb- extra overhead. multipartcache great class though and very useful